# stm32 SPI receive only mode need a transmit?

Tags: stm32, spi, adc

sorry in advance, i am new at this kind of projects.
I tried to implement a connection to an ADC (LTC1609) via SPI. I just want to get the data from the ADC as quick as possible. The ADC has just a output-line, so i chose the "read only mode". But i also tried to use the HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive funktion because i remembered that the spi exchange starts with writeing in the transmit register (at least with the HCS12).
The ADC needs also some additional signals changes between pulling down the NSS and starting the spi connection so i put the NSS in software mode.

The **Cofiguration** looks like this:

```
   static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{
  /* SPI1 parameter configuration*/
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES_RXONLY;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_16BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_4;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  hspi1.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
  hspi1.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }   
}
```

I write a **funktion** to read from ADC and store the data.

```
void LTC1609_ADU_Read(uint8_t *data)
{
        uint8_t buffer_rx[2];

        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, 0);    // NSS low  (Pin PA4) Start 
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, GPIO_PIN_6, 0);    // ADU R/NC low  (Pin PG6) Start conversion
        delay_hns (1);                              // wait 1us (10 x 100ns)
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, GPIO_PIN_6, 1);    // ADU R/NC high  (Pin PG6)
       
        if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOG, GPIO_PIN_8) == 1)    // /BUSY is high? -> start SPI
        {
            if(HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, buffer_rx,2,10)!= HAL_OK);
            {
                SPI_error = HAL_SPI_GetError(&hspi1); // get the SPI error
                Error_Handler();                      // stop in error
            }
        }

        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, 1); // Set ADU /CS high  (Pin PA4) fin
        *data = buffer_rx[1];           // store received data
}
```

In the while(1) i called it like this with a delay of 100 ms for testing:

```
LTC1609_ADU_Read(&buffer_A_rx);
```

**Problem:**
The uC (STM32L4R5ZIT6P) dont start the SPI clk to trigger out the data from ADC. Also the Clock polarity is somtimes low (like i want) and sometimes high [could also be a messuring problem, i messure it with a sheep logic analyser 24Mhz 8CH from amazon].
If i start the programm, it runs into the error handler and the errorcode is 0x20. I found this explaining:
HAL_SPI_ERROR_FLAG              0x00000020U   /*!< Flag: RXNE,TXE, BSY  */

Can anyone give me a tip on what could be the reason? Did iam doing something wrong or could the hardware be damaged? Thanks in advance!

[screenshot signals without clk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLLBy.png)

Comment: The CLK output of the uC was broken. It has been damaged by the ADC during a reboot of the uC. When restarting, the EXT/NINT pin is briefly low (even with pullup). As a result, the ADC switches its CLK input to an output and starts its own CLK. The CLK output of the ADU meets the output of the uC. The output of the uC has lost this battle. I soldered a new Controler to my board and make sure the EXT/NINT Pin of the ADC is always high. Now its working pretty good :)

Answer (score 0):

One problem that I see in your code is that you check the BUSY pin immediately after setting R/C high and abort the transaction if BUSY is low.

According to the datasheet, BUSY line may be low for up to 3 us (`t3`).

[image]

Try waiting for the busy pin to go high, for example by adding a loop as shown below.

```c
void LTC1609_ADU_Read(uint8_t *data)
{
    uint8_t buffer_rx[2];

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, 0);  // NSS low  (Pin PA4) Start
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, GPIO_PIN_6, 0);  // ADU R/NC low  (Pin PG6) Start conversion
    delay_hns(1);                             // wait 1us (10 x 100ns)
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, GPIO_PIN_6, 1);  // ADU R/NC high  (Pin PG6)

    uint8_t retries = 0;
    do {
        delay_hns(1);
    } while (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOG, GPIO_PIN_8) == 0 && ++retries < 5);

    if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOG, GPIO_PIN_8) == 1)  // /BUSY is high? -> start SPI
    {
        if (HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, buffer_rx, 2, 10) != HAL_OK)
        {
            SPI_error = HAL_SPI_GetError(&hspi1);  // get the SPI error
            Error_Handler();                       // stop in error
        }
    }

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, 1);  // Set ADU /CS high  (Pin PA4) fin
    *data = buffer_rx[1];                     // store received data
}
```

Also, there is a stray `;` in your code, on this line:

```c
if(HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, buffer_rx,2,10)!= HAL_OK);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help!    I made the changes and now the functions no longer end up in the error handler. I have also initialized the buffer with a value and noticed that the received process overrides the value with "0".   I don't have a signal on the ADC but I doubt that it is always 0 with a 16bit ADC.

Comment: @T0K4M4K If the answer was helpful, I would appreciate an upvote! Regarding the data, I agree, I wouldn't expect it to be 0, but it's difficult to say what might be the cause. Try checking your schematics and read the datasheet again to see if you may have missed anything. Also, note that you need 17 clocks to read out all the data.